# Commuting Elements in Tensor Products of C*-Algebras

Tags: tensor-products, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I am working on exercise 7.G in the book “K-Theory and C*-Algebras” by Wegge-Olsen.

Let $A$ be some unital C*-algebra, $u$ a unitary in $M_n(A)$, and $u’$ a standard unitary (which is defined to be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying some properties). In the exercise, it says

> Then $u_1:= 1\otimes u$ and $u_2:=\operatorname{diag}(u’,1,\dots, 1)\otimes 1$ are commuting unitaries in $B:=M_n((SA)^\sim)$.

Here $M_n((SA)^\sim)=(SA)^\sim \otimes M_n$ where $M_n$ denotes the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices, $SA$ is the suspension of $A$ and $(SA)^\sim$ is $SA$ with a unit adjoined.

I cannot see how $u_1$ and $u_2$ are commuting. I suppose 
$$M_n((SA)^\sim)\simeq (SA)^\sim \otimes M_n \subset C(\mathbb{T})\otimes A\otimes M_n.$$
However, $u\in M_n(A)$ and $\operatorname{diag}(u’,1,\dots, 1)\in C(\mathbb{T})\otimes M_n$. That is to say, we should write 
$$u_1=1\otimes \left(\sum_{i,j} u_{i,j}\otimes e_{i,j}\right),$$
$$u_2=u’\otimes e_{1,1}\otimes 1 + \sum_{k\not =1} 1\otimes e_{k,k}\otimes 1.$$
But it does not appear to me that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are commuting?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused at the example for a standard unitary, $t\mapsto \exp(\frac{it}{1+|t|})$  is not in $C_0(\mathbb{R})^\sim$ since  the limit dose not exist when $|t|\to +\infty$. Where is my problem?

Comment: I think $SA=\{f\in C([0,1]\to A): f(0)=f(1)=0\}=\{f\in C(\mathbb{T}\to A): f(1)=0\}$.

Comment: @C.Ding yes you’re right

Comment: @C.Ding I can’t see why the example of standard unitary works either. I was identifying $C_0(\mathbb{R})^\sim$ with $C(\mathbb{T})$